# How to install log4j bundle into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I found that one of my Eclipse installations has `org.apache.log4j` plugin installed. The provider of this plug-in is labeled as "Eclipse Orbit". Probably it was installed as dependency by some other software I don't know. I see no "orbit" sites among available installation sites in Eclipse preferences.

Also I don't see conventional download URL on [Orbit page](http://eclipse.org/orbit/).

So how to find and install `log4j` bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the available builds of the Orbit repository at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/ . Clicking one of those build links will take you to a page that includes the update site URL, which you can use as an "available installation site" to install anything from the Orbit project.